# How to handle lua_error() in Lua when it's fired from C

Tags: dll, lua

I have a C DLL that I load into Lua. The DLL will call lua_error() when there is an error. In Lua I get a message box with an error description. Is there any way for me to handle this better? Some kind of try/catch on Lua's side or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's handled no differently than if your Lua script had called `error`. If you want to call a function that may issue a Lua error (whether C/C++ or Lua), and you want to handle the error condition instead of just stopping, then you should use `pcall` to call the function.

Comment: actually that didn't seem to work or I did it wrong. I have: if pcall(db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test1")) then
 Notify("No error")
else
 Notify("error")
end

Comment: With the above I get the error from db:nrows() which is coming from the DLL. I would have expected to received the "error" msg but I got an error message that is coming from the DLL. Note I'm using LuaJIT but I would think that wouldn't matter.

Comment: @user441521: That is not how you use `pcall`. The proper way to `pcall` is as follows: `pcall(db.nrows, db, "SELECT * FROM test1")`. We pass the function we want to call `db.nros`, follows by its parameters. Remember: `x:y()` syntax is the same as `x.y(x)`, so the first parameter is `db`. The second is the SQL string.